# How to remove warnings from the console log in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm writing an app in react native and I'm having the annoying "Setting a time for a long period of time warning".

I've used this code to remove the yellow-box warning from my phone

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
```

But I still can't figure how to remove that warning from the console log, as you can see here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ2BF.png

Any ideas how I can disable the warning also in the console log? (Without disabling logging itself of course, as I wish to able to debug..)

Edit: not sure if that's matter, I'm using Expo to run my app

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can erase it using the [console module.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements)

**Installation**

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
```

**Via .babelrc (Recommended)**

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = [ ... ];
  const plugins = [["transform-remove-console", { "exclude": [ "error", "warn"] }]];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

Comment: Since I'm using Expo I don't have a .babelrc files
I do have a file called babel.config.js.

I tried to write it as following: 

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
    development: {
      plugins: [ ["transform-remove-console", { "exclude": ["warn"] }] ]
        }
    }
  };
}

But I still see the warning on my console..

Comment: I also tried to write the babel.config.js file like this
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  
  const presets = ['babel-preset-expo'];
  const plugins = [ ["transform-remove-console", { "exclude": ["warn"] }] ];
  
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};

But the warnings still appear in my console..

Comment: Tried it, still seeing the warnings :(

Comment: What I did for now is to go to node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js and remove the the if (__DEV__ && IS_ANDROID && duration > MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS) . Probably not the best solution, but at least I can debug more comfortably..