# How to remove WARN in react native terminal

Tags: react-native, logging, warnings

I want to remove WARN inside react native terminal.
[image]

Tried this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/troubleshooting/

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);
```

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);
```

not also this one
[How to remove warnings from the console log in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539971/how-to-remove-warnings-from-the-console-log-in-react-native)

but no luck

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243680/react-native-another-virtualizedlist-backed-container